# AngularJS: error injecting http interceptor

Tags: angularjs, authentication, http-headers, interceptor

I am implementing token based authentication with AngularJS. The token is created on server and returned to client. After authentication, the token will be added to header of every rest call. I created a authInterceptor:

```
ristoreApp.factory('authInterceptor', function ($rootScope, $q, $window) {
    return {
        request: function (config) {
            config.headers = config.headers || {};
            if ($window.localStorage.getItem("access_token")) {
                config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + $window.localStorage.getItem("access_token");
            }
            return config;
        },
        response: function (response) {
            if (response.status === 401) {
                // handle the case where the user is not authenticated
            }
            return response || $q.when(response);
        }
    };
});
```

Then injected it in my config.js as follows:

```
ristoreApp
.config(function ($httpProvider, authInterceptor, $routeProvider) {

    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('authInterceptor');

    $routeProvider
.......
})
```

However I got the following error:

```
Failed to instantiate module ristoreApp due to: Unknown provider: authInterceptor
```

What is wrong with my way to inject the interceptor?

Comment: Can you post your detail code? It will be better if you add any fiddle/plnkr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this Failed to Instantiate module happens when you have NOT defined

> ristoreApp

in your Routing file.